# how to request in react + spring security?

Tags: reactjs, spring-security

I've been troubled for days by the application of spring security...

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.addFilter(corsFilter);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/manager/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    http.formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login-process")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", false);
}
```

My front-end is React using 3000 port and not in spring source folder. so i think i can't use spring default login form. so i thought it would work if i sent a "POST" request to loginProcessingUrl.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8081/login-process', {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method:"POST",
    body:{"username":"user","password":"d4ddeb71-c76b-43f3-a0af-2f3c0b36bbec"}
})
.then((json) => console.log(json));
```

but i got "http://localhost:8081/login?error" url as response.

username and password is spring gave to me. and if i enter "http://localhost:8081/login"(default login form)  using chrome browser and login with these, it works well. so i don't think username or password is wrong.

i've seen https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-react, but I think it's different from my case where the front end is separated.

what's the problem? should i approach it differently?

Comment: Why havnt you enabled debug logging and checked your logs? Also why are you not using the built in CorsFilter?

Comment: its called `formLogin` you need to post FORM DATA and not JSON